# Can we access Unikong on mobile?

Tags: support, mobile-web, april-fools, unikong

I hear there's a new game in town called Unikong. I can't get to a desktop browser today though and I don't want to miss out! What do?

Answer (score 5):

Scroll to the bottom of the page and tap "full site":

[image]

Then, tap the link in the sidebar:

[image]

Assuming you have a keyboard app that provides arrow keys (like [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard)), you should be able to play as if you were sitting in front of a desktop PC.

Comment: So I guess there's no built in mobile support then?

Comment: @nhinkle Unfortunately, no. https://twitter.com/aalear/status/713153888619257856